# statsmodels _df_model attribute error

Tags: python, statsmodels

This problem originally occurred with real data, but it can be replicated with sample code from the statsmodels website (http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
y = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4]
x = range(1,8)
# x = sm.add_constant(x) # including this line makes no difference
model = sm.OLS.fit(y,x)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
  File "rec.py", line 131, in test2
model = sm.OLS.fit(y,x)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 302, in fit
    if self._df_model is None:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_df_model'
```

No idea what to make of this or how to resolve it. It almost seems like I accidentally triggered some bad internal statsmodels state, especially because previously I had this basic call working on real data (with only a couple of feature columns, stored in a pandas dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove from sm.OLS(Y,X) -> fit , this works, you dont put fit method where it needed

```
import statsmodels.api as sm                                                                                                                                                      

Y = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4]
X = range(1,8)
X = sm.add_constant(X)

model = sm.OLS(Y,X)
results = model.fit()
```

Comment: i dont think this works; calling `results` and `print(results)` after both just give a memory location ( <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper object at 0x0000...)

Comment: @Mike Palmice `print(results.params)` `print(results.tvalues)`